# How do I run to the boat without losing the parrot?

Tags: the-cave

When I try to walk with the parrot to the boat on the right end of the island, the parrot always flees as soon I try to cross the water underneath the hermit's house.

How can I keep the parrot on my shoulder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not jump in the water, but jump carefully down at the right side of the hermits home platform.